# Sending images via SMS, how they did that?

Tags: iphone, image, sms

I Already read so many answers here and there, all confirming that we can't send MMS or images attached with SMS from an iPHone app. But for exeample how this app would did that?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/justwink-greeting-cards/id439880532?mt=8

[image]

that's why I'm asking, if any one may have some hints. THanks.

Comment: A lot of texting apps assign some kind of server-side address and send images through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might send a request back to their server which sends an mms from there?

Comment: Ah ok, so there is no way to do this unless using third party servers and machines? you confirm? :)